# Intellij Pull Requests Tool Windows has errors

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

Intellij version: 2018.3 (183.4284.148)

I am trying to use the feature https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/10/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-github-pull-requests-and-more/ in my Enterprise Github.

When I open the Pull requests tool window it loads pull requests however when I click on any one of them I see an error such as below

[image]

There is not much in the idea logs except may be for this one (not sure if this is actually relevant)

```
2018-12-14 15:56:18,582 [1655214]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: #org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor 
2018-12-14 15:56:28,710 [1665342]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO get information for repository MY_ORG/MY_REPO : Connecting 
2018-12-14 15:56:29,507 [1666139]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO GET : Connected 
2018-12-14 15:56:29,509 [1666141]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO GET : Result extracted 
2018-12-14 15:56:29,519 [1666151]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/search/issues?q=type%3Apr%20repo%3AMY_ORG%2FMY_REPO%20state%3Aopen search issues in repository : Connecting 
2018-12-14 15:56:30,218 [1666850]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/search/issues?q=type%3Apr%20repo%3AMY_ORG%2FMY_REPO%20state%3Aopen GET : Connected 
2018-12-14 15:56:30,458 [1667090]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/search/issues?q=type%3Apr%20repo%3AMY_ORG%2FMY_REPO%20state%3Aopen GET : Result extracted 
2018-12-14 15:56:30,460 [1667092]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/avatars/u/9264? get profile avatar : Connecting 
2018-12-14 15:56:30,461 [1667093]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/avatars/u/7541? get profile avatar : Connecting 
2018-12-14 15:56:31,659 [1668291]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2FMY_COMPANY_URL%2Favatars%2Fu%2F7541%3F GET : Connected 
2018-12-14 15:56:31,660 [1668292]   INFO - .CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader - Error loading image from https://MY_COMPANY_URL/avatars/u/7541? 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageIO.read(stream) must not be null
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiContentHelper.loadImage(GithubApiContentHelper.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1$extractResult$1.convert(GithubApiRequests.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1$extractResult$1.convert(GithubApiRequests.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base$createResponse$1.handleBody(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:214)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1.extractResult(GithubApiRequests.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1.extractResult(GithubApiRequests.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base$execute$1.process(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:122)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:523)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base.execute(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$WithTokenAuth.execute(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.loadAndDownscale(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.access$loadAndDownscale(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:22)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1$1.compute(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1$1.compute(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:22)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$3(CoreProgressManager.java:180)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:180)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1.get(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1.get(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-12-14 15:56:31,676 [1668308]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2FMY_COMPANY_URL%2Favatars%2Fu%2F9264%3F GET : Connected 
2018-12-14 15:56:31,677 [1668309]   INFO - .CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader - Error loading image from https://MY_COMPANY_URL/avatars/u/9264? 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageIO.read(stream) must not be null
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiContentHelper.loadImage(GithubApiContentHelper.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1$extractResult$1.convert(GithubApiRequests.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1$extractResult$1.convert(GithubApiRequests.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base$createResponse$1.handleBody(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:214)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1.extractResult(GithubApiRequests.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequests$CurrentUser$getAvatar$1.extractResult(GithubApiRequests.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base$execute$1.process(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:122)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:523)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base.execute(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$WithTokenAuth.execute(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.loadAndDownscale(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.access$loadAndDownscale(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:22)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1$1.compute(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1$1.compute(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:22)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$3(CoreProgressManager.java:180)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:180)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1.get(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.util.CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader$requestAvatar$1$1.get(CachingGithubUserAvatarLoader.kt:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-12-14 15:56:32,848 [1669480]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/pulls/3863 get pull request : Connecting 
2018-12-14 15:56:33,488 [1670120]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Request: https://MY_COMPANY_URL/api/v3/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/pulls/3863 GET : Connected 
2018-12-14 15:56:33,571 [1670203]  DEBUG - b.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor - Can't get pull request 
org.jetbrains.plugins.github.exceptions.GithubJsonException: Can't get pull request

Couldn't parse GitHub response
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiContentHelper.readJson(GithubApiContentHelper.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequest$Companion$parseJsonResponse$1.convert(GithubApiRequest.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequest$Companion$parseJsonResponse$1.convert(GithubApiRequest.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base$createResponse$1.readBody(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:210)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequest$Companion.parseJsonResponse(GithubApiRequest.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequest$Companion.access$parseJsonResponse(GithubApiRequest.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequest$Get$Json.extractResult(GithubApiRequest.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base$execute$1.process(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:122)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:523)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$Base.execute(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor$WithTokenAuth.execute(GithubApiRequestExecutor.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.pullrequest.data.GithubPullRequestsDataLoader$DataTask.run(GithubPullRequestsDataLoader.kt:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.io.mandatory.JsonMandatoryException: Field 'labels' is mandatory, but missing in response
    at org.jetbrains.io.mandatory.NullCheckingFactory$1.read(NullCheckingFactory.java:57)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiContentHelper.readJson(GithubApiContentHelper.kt:43)
    ... 27 more
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on yole's answer (not enough karma) and I couldn't pinpoint your profile on youtrack but I need some more logs to determine the root-cause of the issue.

Please enable debug logs (Help - Debug Log Settings...) for the following categories:

`#org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor`

Then please reproduce the issue and share the entire logs folder zipped in the youtrack issue.
See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085 to locate the logs.

Comment: Is there an ETA at least please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. I've [reported it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202947) to our issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. If there are any workarounds we could possibly do in our enterprise git setup to make some progress that would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue appears to be `Field 'labels' is mandatory, but missing in response`. The field was implemented in GitHub Enterprise 2.13 only, and earlier versions do not return it in response.

The issue has been fixed in dev version and the will be backported to 2018.3 soon - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200881

As a side note, GitHub Enterprise 2.12 has been discontinued https://enterprise.github.com/releases/series/2.12  and most likely it will be updated soon in your organization, and PR will work even with the current IDE version

Comment: Just to clarify we use 2.11 version of GHE (it is due for an update though)

Comment: Any version before 2.13 does not return the `labels` field in the response and Pull request list will not load.

Comment: So I updated Intellij again today and it still doesn't work. Are you saying that it wont work until we also upgrade our GHE from 2.11? If so that is a major inconvenience!

Comment: Please take a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200881, especially the Fixed in builds field. Unless your version is higher than the one specified there, it does not include the fix.