# Failed to create GitHub Repository Can't create user repository Can't parse GitHub response

Tags: android-studio, github

Each time I attempt to Share to Github from Android Studio I receive this error.

Steps Followed:

Installed git

Created a Personal Access Token on Github

Logged in with the token on Android Studio

Attempted to Share to GitHub and received the error

Answer (score 0):

There was a [similar error (for pull request, not share)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53483973/6309) before which suggested that a mandatory field was missing in answer.

In your case, if you are seeing, when sharing to github.com (not GHE, an on-proemise GitHub for Enterprise)

[image: Can't parse GitHub response]

It is possible GitHub has changed their response when [Creating a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository).

If you are already at the latest Android Studio version, try and [enable the debug option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522266/6309) (Help - Debug Log Settings...) for the following categories:

```
#org.jetbrains.plugins.github.api.GithubApiRequestExecutor
```

That should show you what is missing in the answer, trigger the parsing error.

---

As mentioned by the [OP J.Correa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10022023/j-correa) in the comments, the workaround is to `git push` one's project directly from command line to GitHub.

You can use for that the GitHub official [`cli/cli`](https://github.com/cli/cli) project and its `gh` command

```sh
cd ~/Projects/my-project
# Create a repository for the current directory.
~/Projects/my-project$ gh repo create
✓ Created repository user/my-project on GitHub
✓ Added remote https://github.com/user/my-project.git
~/Projects/my-project$
```

Comment: Apologies on the late response, unfortunately the above did not work for me, I ended up downloading Git, and used git to send to GitHub

Comment: @J.Correa Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added a workaround based on the official GitHub `gh` CLI tool.